# Why does the `updatedb` program run so fast?

Tags: performance, updatedb

Usually when I have programs that are doing a full disk scan and going over all files in the system they take a very long time to run. Why does updatedb run so fast in comparison?

Comment: `find -xdev` scan is very fast, try this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/379827/208590 ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer depends on the version of `locate` you’re using, but there’s a fair chance it’s [`mlocate`](https://pagure.io/mlocate), whose `updatedb` runs quickly by avoiding doing full disk scans:

> mlocate is a locate/updatedb implementation.  The 'm' stands for "merging":
>   updatedb reuses the existing database to avoid rereading most of the file
>   system, which makes updatedb faster and does not trash the system caches as
>   much.

(The database stores each directory’s timestamp, `ctime` or `mtime`, whichever is newer.)

Like most implementations of `updatedb`, `mlocate`’s will also skip file systems and paths which it is configured to ignore. By default there are none in `mlocate`’s case, but distributions typically provide a basic `updatedb.conf` which ignores networked file systems, virtual file systems etc. (see [Debian’s configuration file](https://salsa.debian.org/tfheen/mlocate/blob/master/debian/updatedb.conf) for example; this is standard practice in Debian, so GNU’s `updatedb` is [configured similarly](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/findutils/blob/master/debian/locate.cron.daily)).

Comment: Fairly good question and answer, did not even know there were "differencial" scannings.

Comment: Thanks! I had never noticed that modifying a file also changes the ctime and mtime of all its parent directories.

Comment: @hugomg I don't think it actually does. It should only change the `mtime` of its immediate parent.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, `mlocate` cares about `ctime` and `mtime` which implies it cares only of whether list of directory entries is still the same ( no removed or added files), which means it doesn't care about actual files themselves. Is that correct ?

Comment: @Sergiy: Of course.  `locate` isn't `grep -R`.  It does not read file content.

Comment: @Kevin I'm well aware of the difference. I'm just interested in `mlocate` behavior and how it would handle certain corner cases, since I've my own similar project for a database of files.   For instance, `vim` replaces original file with new, thus changing inode number and modifying directory even if filename is the same.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to checking modification times, `mlocate` also ignores certain subtrees of the file system that have lots of uninteresting or potentially duplicate files, as specified in /etc/updatedb.conf (and described in [man updatedb.conf](https://linux.die.net/man/5/updatedb.conf)):

- Bind mounts
- Some kinds of file systems (9p, afs, bdev, etc)
- VCS repository databases (.git, .hg, etc)
- Some hard-coded directories (/media, /tmp, /var/spool/cups, etc).

Comment: This isn’t the case by default though, so the base behaviour depends on the distribution being used. (Other `updatedb` implementations also support configured exclusions.)

Comment: Indeed. I was describing the defaults for Fedora.