# How could updatedb run quickly by avoiding doing full disk scans (maybe not mtime)

Tags: linux, locate, updatedb

How is it possible for updatedb to run very fast by avoiding doing full disk scans? Since mtime of parent folder is not affected by files in subfolders.

In [Why does the `updatedb` program run so fast?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/492045/584345)

> @hugomg I don't think it actually does. It should only change the
> mtime of its immediate parent. – @Kusalananda

I searched but cannot find the answer.

Comment: Perhaps `updatedb` is misconfigured at your site, and isn't indexing what you think. Read `man updatedb` and look at how you call `updatedb` on your system, start with `less /etc/crontab`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `updatedb` is run for the first time, there is no way to avoid scanning every directory.

But on subsequent scans, if a directory's `mtime` is unchanged from its old entry in the `locate` database, there are no new files and no new subdirectories - so instead of scanning the complete directory, `updatedb` can just use its old database to know the names of any existing sub-directories. So it can proceed directly to checking the `mtime`s of those subdirectories, and apply the same rule to them.

In other words, if a filesystem is unchanged since the previous `updatedb` run, the only thing `updatedb` needs to do to confirm it is to `stat()` each directory entry it already has in its database, and check that its `mtime` remains unchanged.

Only directories whose `mtime` has changed will need a full directory scan: that will uncover any new, renamed or deleted files, links and sub-directories. If new/renamed sub-directories are found, they will need to be fully scanned too.